# asp.net make function from jquery code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, qtip

I am using Qtip jquery plugin for my tooltips and because I have many items that need this I do not want to manually do it for each, bad coding anyway.

This is the JS code:

```
$('#<%= textlink.ClientID %>').qtip({               
    position: { 
          corner: {
                      target: 'topRight', 
                      tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
            }
              },                                    
        style:{ 
            name: 'dark',
            tip: 'bottomLeft',
            border:
              {
            width: 3,
            radius: 7
        }
    } 
});
```

and

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="textlink" runat="server" Text="some text" ToolTip="some other text"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I will have many linkbutton objects, so how can I create a function from the JS code above and call it on mouse over of the linkbutton action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
<asp:LinkButton cssClass="qTip" ID="textlink" runat="server" Text="some text" ToolTip="some other text"></asp:LinkButton>

$('.qTip').qtip({               
    position: { 
          corner: {
                      target: 'topRight', 
                      tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
            }
              },                                    
        style:{ 
            name: 'dark',
            tip: 'bottomLeft',
            border:
              {
            width: 3,
            radius: 7
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Put a class on the `LinkButton` and use a class selector in your jQuery

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="textlink" cssClass="qtip" runat="server" Text="some text" ToolTip="some other text"></asp:LinkButton>
```

```js
$('.qtip').qtip({               
    //...
});
```